# Create a Flag based on a condition from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working to create a Yes/No flag. I have a table of Order Numbers and other table of order numbers with associated Queue Codes. I need to check if a order has passed from some queue codes. I have tried this code but it's not working.

```
SELECT  Order,WI,Status,IF (QUEUE_CODE in ('AXYZ'),"Yes","No") AS FLAG
FROM Table1,Table2 
WHERE Table1.WI=Table2.WI
```

Table1-

```
 Order          WI            Status
161100971/1 W578541-27NOV17 Completed
171203176   N/A             Completed
110403010/3 W874906-28DEC17 Completed
```

Table2-

```
QUEUE_CODE          WI
AXYZ           W578541-27NOV17
ABCD           W578541-27NOV17
ABCD           W874906-28DEC17
CDEF           W874906-28DEC17
```

Result needs to be -

```
Order           WI              Status      Flag
161100971/1     W578541-27NOV17 Completed   Yes
171203176       N/A             Completed   No
110403010/3     W874906-28DEC17 Completed   No
```

Comment: Please feel free to stop writing comma joins. Explicit join syntax was added to the SQL standard over a *quarter of a century* ago. Comma joins are error prone.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2012+ you can use `IIF`, otherwise, use `CASE WHEN`. Please, when joining tables use the following syntax:

```
SELECT Order,T1.WI,Status, IIF (QUEUE_CODE in ('AXYZ'), 'Yes','No') AS FLAG
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.WI=T2.WI;
```

Your syntax is obsolete and hard to read when many objects are joined.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query: You need to replace IF with CASE WHEN

```
SELECT  Order,WI,Status,case when QUEUE_CODE in ('AXYZ') then 'Yes' else 'No' end AS FLAG
FROM Table1 inner join Table2 
on Table1.WI=Table2.WI
```

Comment: Oh God. How Can I forget case when !! Thank you so much for answering this. All solutions are working.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using table prefixes 
SELECT  Table1.Order,Table1.WI,Table1.Status,IF (Table2.QUEUE_CODE in ('AXYZ'),"Yes","No") AS FLAG
FROM Table1,Table2 
WHERE Table1.WI=Table2.WI
```